# Extract CDATA content from an XML file

Tags: php, regex, xml, preg-match, text-extraction

I am trying to parse PHPIDS's XML rule list (downloadable on their site http://phpids.org/), against the entered URL using the XML's regular expressions.

Now, I know very little about regex, and I've tried looking around and I haven't found much information on it which I've found helpful.

What I'd like to do is something like this (psuedo)

```
if URL == regex die();
```

This is my latest attempt, of many:

```
$file = "default_filter.xml";
$load = simplexml_load_file($file);

$regex = $load->filter->rule;
$url = explode(" ", "http://localhost/test.php");
$url2 = "http://localhost/test.php";
if (in_array($regex, $url))
{
    echo "bad url";
}
if (preg_match($regex, $url2))
{
    echo "bad url";
}
//The above gives me Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '|' in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 12
//Which, already I don't understand regex so I don't know why the above is a problem.
```

If I can get it to work, I'll loop through the rules, but for now I'm just trying 1 regex to get it working.

This is the regex which is being pulled from the XML file:

```
<rule><![CDATA[(?:"[^"]*[^-]?>)|(?:[^\w\s]\s*\/>)|(?:>")]]></rule>
```

although I do not understand one bit of that.

Comment: You need to add delimeters to your regex.  Try `preg_match('@'.$regex.'@',$url2)`

Comment: Thanks, and how would i test whether it's working (i.e enter " ' , etc) using those regex's?

Answer (score 5):

About the only thing I can say is the [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) are missing. Given that the `$regex` contains only the regex and not the `<![CDATA[` portion this should work:

```
if(preg_match('#'.$regex.'#',$url2))
```

Give that a shot.

Comment: Thanks, and how would i test whether it's working (i.e enter " ' , etc) using those regex's?

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see this part ever working: `if(in_array($regex,$url)){echo "bad url";}`
I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve with that condition statement.

As for extracting the regex pattern from your XML rule, I can give you some guidance via the following test code:

```
$inputs=array(
  "empty"=>'',
  "doublequote-greater"=>'">"',  // first regex condition match
  "dollar-slash-greater"=>'$/>', // second regex condition match
  "greater-doublequote"=>'>"',  // third regex condition match
  "text"=>'<a>'
);
$rule='<rule><![CDATA[(?:"[^"]*[^-]?>)|(?:[^\w\s]\s*\/>)|(?:>")]]></rule>';
$regex=(preg_match("/<rule><!\[CDATA\[\K.*?(?=\]\])/",$rule,$match)?"/$match[0]/":FALSE);

if($regex){
    foreach($inputs as $k=>$v){
        if(preg_match($regex,$v)){
            echo "Bad ($k): $v\n";
        }else{
            echo "Good ($k): $v\n";
        }
    }
}else{
    echo "Failed to extract regex pattern from XML rule: $rule";
}
```

Output:

> Good (empty):
>   Bad (doublequote-greater): ">"
>   Bad (dollar-slash-greater): $/>
>   Bad (greater-doublequote): >"
>   Good (text):

For a break down of your regex pattern and to continue learning/experimenting, I recommend: https://regex101.com/